# MongoDB Aggregate Count Strange Behavior

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

this mongo command (1) returns 100

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {"events._id":{$exists:true}}},{$unwind: "$events"},{$match: {"events._id":{$exists:true}}},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

this mongo command (2) returns 80

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:true}}},{$unwind: "$events"},{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:true}}},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

this mongo command (2) returns 15

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:false}}},{$unwind: "$events"},{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:false}}},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

in other words, the first command returns the total count of events in my collection, 100. The second command returns those events where 'field' exists, 80.  The third command returns those events where 'field' doesn't exist, 15. Shouldn't (1) + (2) = 100? How do I get the 5 missing events?

Comment: first pipeline is using `events._id`, second and third using `events.field`, that could be the reason. can you change `events._id` to `events.field` in first query and share the count?

Comment: then I would get command 1 to be the same as command 2, no?

Comment: please share the output of `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$events"},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])`

Comment: 100. same as command 1.

Comment: also the count of `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$events"},{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:false}}},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])` & `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$events"},{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:true}}},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])`

Comment: ok. you're onto something here. asking for db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$events"},{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:false}}},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}]) gave me 20. Why does this, db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:false}}},{$unwind: "$events"},{$match: {"events.field":{$exists:false}}},{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}]),  return 15???

Answer (score 1):

In `$unwind` pipeline, you need to preserve the empty or null arrays using field `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` else that the missing or null arrays be filtered and will not be passed to next pipeline.

In your collection some of the documents don't have `events` or `events.field` field

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { $unwind:  { path : "$events", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true } },
        { $match: {"events.field":{ $exists:false } } },
        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
    ]
)
```

sample collection

```
> db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5b0a3dc2a7348cbc592b9e"), "name" : "1", "events" : { "field" : "1" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5b0a3dc2a7348cbc592b9f"), "name" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5b0a3dc2a7348cbc592ba0"), "name" : "3", "events" : { "field" : "2" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5b0a3dc2a7348cbc592ba1"), "name" : "1", "events" : { "field" : "1" } }
>
```

total count

```
> db.collection.count()
4
> 
>
```

count of `events.field exists`

```
> db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { $unwind:  { path : "$events", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true } }, 
        { $match: { "events.field": { $exists : true } } }, 
        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } } 
    ] 
)
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 3 }
>
```

count of `events.field does not exist`

```
> db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { $unwind:  { path : "$events", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true } }, 
        { $match: { "events.field": { $exists : false } } }, 
        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } } 
    ] 
)
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 1 }
> 
>
```

Comment: I added the preserveNullAndEmptyArrays flag but still get the same results

Comment: @PanikosStavrou can you post some sample documents with/without the events array?

Comment: >  { "_id" : ..., "events" : { "field" : "1", "anotherfield" : "1"  } }
    { "_id" : ..., "events" : { "otherfield" : "1" } }
    { "_id" : ..., "events" : { "field" : "1", "otherfield" : "1"   } }
    { "_id" : ..., "events" : { "otherfield" : "1", "anotherfield" : "1" } }

Comment: having a hard time formatting the above. anyway, i'm very sure all records in my collection have events arrays in them.